# Html is still visible in CodeIgniter using if else

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter

I'm here trying to make if else condition to hiding the html part if `$addons_facts` var is empty. I am making the addon visible on the food item if the `$addons_facts` var is not empty.

```
 <?php    $addon_data = $this->addons_model->get_addon_by_menu_id($menu_details['id']);
          $addons_facts = json_decode($addon_data->addon_fact, true);
    ?>
        <?php if(!empty($addons_facts) && $addons_facts !=='') : ?>
         <div class="form-group">
               <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                    <?php 
                            foreach ($addons_facts as $key => $addon_fact) : ?>
                              
                                 <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-1">
                                            <div class="checkbox">
                                                <label for="check">
                                                    <input type="checkbox" id="check" />
                                                    <span class="fake-input"></span>
                                                </label>
                                            </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-7 text-left">
                                       <?php echo sanitize($key); ?>
                                    </div> 
                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                        <?php echo currency(sanitize($addon_fact));?>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
```

**When data is present in `$addons_facts`**

[image: here]

**When data is absent `$addons_facts`**

[image: here]

As you can clearly see that when data is **not** present and the **html** is still visible **(checkbox or $)**. I already tried `if else` both but unable to figure it out what is going wrong and why if condition not hiding the whole content within `if{}`.

Comment: If you print_r or var_dump `$addons_facts` when its suppost to be empty, what does it output?

Comment: Array([]) is the output when its empty

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP: if !empty & empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2347061/php-if-empty-empty)

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out the solution by this:  `<?php if(!empty($key)) : ?>`

```
<div class="form-group">
                   <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                        <?php 
                                foreach ($addons_facts as $key => $addon_fact) : ?>
                                  <?php if(!empty($key)) : ?>
                                    <?php $randomNum = substr(str_shuffle("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTVWXYZ"), 0, 10); ?>
                                     <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-1">
                                                <div class="checkbox">
                                                    <label for="<?php echo $randomNum; ?>">
                                                        <input type="checkbox" id="<?php echo $randomNum; ?>" />
                                                        <span class="fake-input"></span>
                                                    </label>
                                                </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-7 text-left">
                                           <?php echo sanitize($key); ?>
                                        </div> 
                                        <div class="col-3">
                                            <?php echo sanitize($addon_fact) ? currency(sanitize($addon_fact)) :'';?>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                     <?php endif; ?>
                                <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```